# Proper way to debug statement-level performance

Tags: python, performance

I have a view, and for each statement I am putting a `time.time()` in it. For example:

```
t1 = time.time()
worker_stats = get_worker_stats(worker_id)
t2 = time.time()
```

At the end of the program, I then give results for each section of code. For example, for the above:

> WorkerStats = t2 - t1

This works fine for a short-term solution, but for production it has these `time.time()` statements sprinkled incessantly throughout the code. Is there a better way to track statement-performance, or is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using timers is in general not a good way to measure performance anyway.

To increase program performance, one in general uses a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html):

You can run this as:

```
import cProfile

cProfile.run('get_worker_stats(worker_id)')
```

Or you can decide to **remove all timer/profile statements in your code**, and run it with:

```
python -m cProfile program.py
```

In that case `python` will run the program with the profiler attached.

The nice thing is that a profiler keeps track of **all** method calls that originate from the top level call, the number of times a function is called, the average performance etc.

By calling the profiler at the top, you can simply omit all time tracking in the middle: simply remove the tracking statement at the top.

Furthermore you can configure the profile for instance to write the results to a separate file so that - in case you forget to remove the profiler statement(s) - you don't write to the output channel.

This [talk at *PyCon*](http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdywg/) demonstrates how you can then analyze the obtained results.